# Early-Late TED in SDR

Tags: digital-communications

I am reading about Early Late TED from "Software Defined Radio using Matlab & Simulink and the RTL-SDR". This is from the book:

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Now I'm trying to understand the 11.7 formula in a 'for dummies', very simplistic way. This is my thinking and I could be way off. If early-late uses 3 samples, I assume:

x(kTs) is the E point on the graphs

x(deltaTs) is the next sample, or the P point

tau hat is... who is tau hat? Where does it come from?

I'm sure I'm missing or misinterpreting something but I don't know what. Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**: One important detail that I forgot to mention... The book actually explains that tau hat is the timing estimate (as opposed to the ideal timing). What I don't understand is where it comes from/how it's calculated. Also, I didn't have a clear picture how it fits in the formula 11.7.

The other thing; I watched [a video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3sLmrExl3iM&t=600s) which made the formula clear. With all due respect to the professor, it was a struggle to understand the English, but the content was crystal clear and it finally clicked in my mind. Now the formula 11.7 makes sense. It's one of those things where, after I understand it, I say "duh, what was the hang-up, that was pretty basic".

Anyway, what's left to ponder is how tau hat, the timing estimate, is being calculated. For this I haven't found any information yet.

Comment: If it's not explained in the book (it'd be real bad if they use undefined quantities or variables), I'd suggest reading Gardner's paper directly, it's quite approachable.

Comment: Is the paper publicly available? I can find online papers on various modifications, but not the actual paper.

Comment: I don't know -- if you're a student, then you might be able to get it from your library.

Comment: Not a student...